# How to prevent value change inside $watch

Tags: angularjs

I'm $watching a scope value that can be edited by the user in an input field.
I want to make sure that newValue is always a number and if it isn't, keep the oldValue until user types in a correct number value.

How can I do that?

What I'm currently doing is this (inside the link function of a directive):

```
scope.$watch('count',function(newValue,oldValue)
{
    newValue=parseInt(newValue,10);
    if(isNaN(newValue))
    {
        newValue=oldValue;
    }
});
```

Is that the proper way of doing that, or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to prevent to users to type string in text field? or only in watch?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm thinking about that, but for now I just want the input to not be set on the scope model unless it's how I want it.

Comment: Define "correct number value". Given your question, @MannyD's answer is perfectly valid answer.

Comment: You can letters numbers in a number input and it has up and down arrows which I don't need. "Correct number" is a series of if-checks I want to apply depending on other vars in the scope.

Comment: @Stewie not at all, sometimes designers don't want to show "ugly" `type="number"`

Comment: In that case you should have pointed out in your question that you don't want to use `type="number"` because of the arrows.

Comment: I disagree because using a number typed input does not solve the problem. Again, you can enter string values in a number input.

Comment: Model won't receive string value if input type is set to "number".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would write `$watch` like:

```
 $scope.$watch('count',function(newValue,oldValue)
{
  if(newValue !== undefined && !newValue.match(/^[\d]+$/g)){

    $scope.count=oldValue;
  }
});
```

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a96S614rksk7lmYIJMR7?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Aha, so `newValue=oldValue` or `return oldValue` isn't good enough? I have to explicitly set the value for `f1 on `scope`?

Comment: OK. Was thinking that whatever `newValue` ends up being after the `$watch` handler executes gets set on the `$scope.f1` var.

Comment: By the way, I think you should remove the `\s` from the RegEx, so `\d` or `[0-9]`.

Comment: Doesn't this repeatedly trigger $watch? For example, if oldValue = 3 and newValue = 3a, $scope.count is set to 3. $watch triggers again oldValue = 3a and newValue = 3

Comment: @Lizzie when you had `3` and type `a`, you enter to `if` and give to count new value that does another trigger to watch but always in 2nd loop you doesnt enter to `if`. So there  is no digest cycle plroblem. You have plunker, just test it: http://plnkr.co/edit/KC4j7T28QE4T7xWacUgu?p=preview

Comment: Yes I did :) Sorry if I sounded silly. I meant in a different situation where you check newValue !== oldValue, "do something" and then revert newValue change to oldValue based on a condition. This "do something" will be executed for unwanted value as well. Should I ask a new question for this?

Comment: @Lizzie Sure you can,

Comment: Just to note, if you also have a function on `ng-change`, that function is invoked before the watch (with a potentially invalid value) and not again once you set the value back to `oldValue`. For that reason I'd suggest avoiding mixing `ng-change` with `$watch`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing with the solution by @Maxim is that it needs the model to be hardcoded. It works but an improved solution could look like this:

```
$scope.$watch('count',function(newValue,oldValue,scope) {
  if(newValue !== undefined && !newValue.match(/^[\d]+$/g)){
    scope[this.exp] = oldValue;
  }
});
```

- added "scope" to the parameters.
- find the model name using "this.exp"
- store the oldValue directly to the model on the scope

Comment: That's very nice. However, I'm worried about `this.exp` which is not documented so if they decide to change the name it won't work anymore. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Francisc this is set to the watch object from the $digest call (`watch.fn(value, ((last === initWatchVal) ? value : last), current);`). So as it is a local variable it could change and you will lose this functionality.

Comment: Thanks. [extra chars]